# How to specify list size using FactoryBoy

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, mocking, factory-boy

Let's assume i have this model:

```
class FooContainerModel(object):
    def __init__(self, foos):
        self.foos = foos
```

I want to be able to decide how many foos will be created at creation time, eg.

```
model = FooContainerFactory(count=15)
```

Tried factories like

```
class FooContainerFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = FooContainerModel

    foos = factory.List([Foo() for _ in xrange(20)]) # fixed amount
    foos = factory.lazy_attribute(lambda o: [Foo() for _ in xrange(20)]) # same
```

Of course I can manually create list of Foo() with desired length and instantiate FooContainerModel, but it's not what I want. Any solutions?

Comment: Can't you just override `__init__()` on the `ContainerFactory`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got no idea how FactoryBoy works, but this strategy usually works for me when I need dynamic properties on fields in Django models:

```
def FooContainerFactory(factory.Factory):

    def __init__(self, count=20, *args, **kwargs):
        self.foos = factory.List([Foo() for _ in range(20)])
        super(FooContainerFactory, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = FooContainerModel
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was any ready to use solution in FactoryBoy, but your way is too easy and straightforward to try to complicate it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `create_batch` method.

```
models = FooContainerFactory.create_batch(size=15)
```

If you want to create 15 absolutely different models you might need to use [Sequences](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#sequences) and [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)(in addition)

Comment: I know about `create_batch`. I wanted another thing - let's assume I have an Author class that has a list of books. I was wondering if it's possible to easily create Factory configuration for Author that would allow me to call it like `AuthorFactory(books__count=10)` and it will create 10 books under the hood using BooksFactory.

Comment: Divide it into 2 steps:
1) `author = AuthorFactory()`
2) `books = BookFactory.create_batch(size=10, author=author)`

Comment: Sure, I know that ;) Just wanted to know if there is any ready to use way of doing this in one line